# What material is Magneto's helmet made of?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In the X-Men series, there is a helmet which can block a telepath's ability to read somebody's mind. What material is that helmet made of?

Comment: Afaik it's just simple metal. However given it's form it uses an effect comparable to the [Faraday Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect). Not 100% sure on that though, so won't post an answer. This might also change based on which incarnation of Magneto (like classic comics vs. movie trilogy) you consider.

Comment: Everybody knows that hats with those capabilities are always tinfoil.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**In the comic canon, Magneto's helmet is made out of whatever metals Magneto has available. Any strong metal appears to be usable.**

- He reshapes the metal at the molecular level so it has the anti-psionic abilities necessary to keep his mind from being affected by telepathic abilities. The metal is likely highly magnetized, since strong magnetic fields reduce or prevent telepaths from being able to read minds. See: [Faraday Cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage).
- Note: he does not need the helmet to protect his mind from being read. An active use of his power can do the same thing. The helmet allows him to not have to focus on and put any effort into protecting his mind, and gives an added layer of protection against Alpha level telepaths such as Jean Grey or Professor X.

We have watched him shape his helmet, even when it is lost or damaged, out of scrap metal if necessary. Magneto does not appear to be concerned about losing a helmet and always seems to have a new one, even if it is taken or destroyed.

Comment: The helmet's previous owner didn't have metal-bending powers to do what you are saying..

Comment: @SachinShekhar There was no previous owner in the comics. He only took the helmet from Shaw in First Class.

Comment: There's a lot of assertions here, but precious little actual evidence